# shuffle Numbers without triple Repeat in row

Tags: php, random, repeat, triples

What is the fastest way to shuffle an array with numbers without repeating trible times in a row

```
shuffleX(array(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1),2)
```

1,1,1,2,2,2,... Bad

1,1,2,2,1,2,... Good

1,2,1,2,1,2,... Good

```
function shuffleX($arr, $max=2){

 ...
} 
$arr=array(1,2,1,1,2,2);
shuffleX($arr,2);
```

Comment: What is a tribble?

Comment: I am not sure but may be you want like this:- https://3v4l.org/BaU8o  (data will not repeat in chunks of three)

Comment: works not really

Comment: $max= maximum 2 repeats in a row. I found out that this function is not that easy, because you could have a lot of unused Numbers at the End of the array. This algorithm is a little bit harder to develop that i thought before

Comment: This works perfectly https://3v4l.org/QCeJ2

Comment: @dazzafact  "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my dirty Solution with an "while Check"
https://3v4l.org/bFjZ5

```
function shuffleX($arr, $max=3){
    $raw=$arr;
    $x=0;
    $s=md5('random_string');
    while(1){$x++;
        shuffle($arr);
            //Build string out of Arr for repeating variables to check
            $f2=join($s,$arr);
            $break=true;

            foreach($raw as $k=>$v){
                //Check for repeating variables each Value (forward and Backward)
                $f=str_repeat($v.$s,$max);
                $fa=str_repeat($s.$v.'',$max);  

                if(preg_match('#'.$f.'#',$f2) OR preg_match('#'.$fa.'#',$f2)){
                    $break=false;
                }

        }
        if($break===true){return $arr;}
        if($x>(count($arr)*1000)){// if nothing found after x Times break or give an empty array
            return array('unpossible');
        }
    }

}
$arr=array(1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1);
print_r(shuffleX($arr,3));
```

Comment: could you please test once my final modified code? let me know it worked for you or not?